# TCP to listen and do other things while listening

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, listener

So I have a C code set up to be both client and server. What I need to do is be able to check to see if someone has tried to set up a connection with me after each time my menu has printed. If someone has tried, connect with them. If they haven't tried, print the menu again. I am currently listening on the server but how do I set it up so i can check my listen queue without having it block my code. Like a small check to see if someone has or not.

Comment: In a word, `select().`

Comment: the code should not care about how many are trying to connect.  The next instruction, after checking the return code from listen() should be accept(), which normally blocks.  When execution passes to the next instruction after accept, the return value from accept is a socket number to use for communication with the client.  to do other things while listening/accepting, start another thread before calling listen() and do the other things in the new thread

Answer (score 0):

This may help: [Trouble with socket connection in C and Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26695134/trouble-with-socket-connection-in-c-and-linux). I was having trouble with only being able to establish one connection and the server dropping the client afterwords. As the post above stated you want to accept the connection than either start a new thread that will act on the new client socket or fork a new process that will handle the client. Either way works, but there seems to be more examples online that use the fork method. If you could post your code, I could take a look at it and see if I could offer some help.

I forgot I did not put the corrected code up after the question was answered. The only code that has changed since then is the accept function

```
int server_accept_connections(server *serv, int (*process_data)(char *buffer, ssize_t length, int client_scoket))
{
    int result = 0;
    int length = sizeof((serv)->client_addr);
    char *buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 250);

    if (buffer) {       
        while (result == 0) {
            serv->client_socket = accept(serv->sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)(serv)->client_addr, &length);

            pid_t pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0)
                result = -1;

            else if (pid == 0) { /* client code */
                close(serv->sockfd); //the client doesn't need to listen
                ssize_t data_length = recv(serv->client_socket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                result = (* process_data)(buffer, data_length, serv->client_socket);
                close(serv->client_socket);
                break; //have the child leave the while loop -- probably not what I want
            }
            else {
                close(serv->client_socket);
            }       
        }
    }
    else
        result = -1;

    free(buffer);
    return result;
}
```

The code is still a little rough, but hopefully you can get the idea of how to handle multiple connections.